# Error when running Lotus Domino agent

Tags: lotus-notes

I wrote an Lotus Domino agent to transfer Domlog.nsf data to DB2 database. When I run agent I get:

```
Error: Cannot find Connector 'DB2COPY2'
```

DB2COPY2 is name of my DB2 client or instance, don't know how you call it.
And next error is (probably due to first error)

```
NO RESUME
```

In the LotusScript I got line  `Dim conn As New LCConnection("DB2COPY2")`

Any ideas on first error? Thank you.

Comment: Is the DB2- connector installed on the server and can the "service"- User access the connection information? When working with ODBC you have to configure the ODBC as System- DSN, not User- DSN, I don't know if there is something similar with DB2...

Comment: I don't think I have it installed, unless it comes by default. Where do I get it?

Comment: You need to download and install the DB2 CLI drivers and then configure the connection on the machine/server that the code is going to run on. The name of the connection you configure will be the name you set on the LCConnection properties. But, your call to create the LCConnection object would be:

    Dim conn as New LCConnection("db2")

Answer (score 0):

You want to access a data source without installing a driver for it. Its like wanting to drive a car without a key... This does not work. To access odbc data sources, you need tominstall an odbc driver (from the vendor of your database system). To accesss db2 databases, you need a db2- client installed on the server (delivered by ibm if you have the relevant licenses).

In addition you could install decs (for free) or lei (quite cost intensive) to make it easier to configure the access to the data sources, but it will not make the drivers obsolete...

Comment: I got the driver, now where do I put it? Cause it has no install, and I can't find explanation on the internet.

Comment: i have no idea, as I do not know, which driver from which vendor you have... And I am not a DB2 specialist at all...

Comment: I think I found it. Thanks Tode.

Comment: I installed using this guide: http://www.withdata.com/ad/tips/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver.html but still same error.